# prefix"cid:" is mandatory for sending any attachment in SOAP

Tags: html, soap, attachment

I want to ask whether prefix `cid:` is mandatory for sending any attachment. If `cid:` prefix is not there how server side will read the attachment? Does rfc say anything clear about this? I have read rfc2392 but still don't understand.

Comment: I am sorry but your question is incomprehensible. If you would follow at least [this checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163), it would help a lot.

Comment: Improved wording.

Comment: Whether "cid:" prefix is mandatory when Client send any attachment in soap request to the Server?